# Should I use Server key or Legacy server key to send Post request to FCM Api over HTTP1.1?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In *console.firebase.com* under *Settings/CloudMessaging* there are two keys

- Server key
- Legacy server key

Which key should I use in order to send a POST request to FCM API? I am sending the request over HTTP1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use either key to authorize [legacy HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) as documented here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_legacy_protocol_send_requests

If you hover over the `?` in the console next to the legacy key, you will see a notice suggesting that **you should upgrade to the newer service key**.

If you're using the [new v1 send request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages), you'll need a service account instead, as shown here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_v1_send_requests

Comment: I am using a Vapor server written in Swift. I am reading [Build Send Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) and I wonder, do I have to create a JSON Web Token and sign it with the new version of Server key I get from Firebase console? I find no details about this. The docs says, the token is `short lived`. Does it mean it lasts for 60 mins? Please point me to the right resource to learn more. If I have to build JWT, I think I have to do it in REST as I see no Firebase SWIFT library for server. Many thanks

Comment: This sounds like a different question than the one that was originally asked.  If you have a followup question, could you post that separately?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_legacy_protocol_send_requests), starting from March 2020, FCM stopped creating legacy server keys. Existing legacy server keys will continue to work, but we recommend that you instead use the newer version of key labeled Server key in the Firebase console.